# Changes to server configuration option remote access are not supported in SQL Database Managed Instances

Tags: sql-server-2019, remote, azure-sql-managed-instance

Having just set up our new SQL Server Managed Instance, restored a sample database for testing, and run Azure's vulnerability assessment, it produces this **high risk** finding:

> VA2120 - Features that may affect security should be disabled
>
> The more SQL Server features and services you enable, the larger its
> surface attack area becomes, making your system more vulnerable to
> potential attacks. These fetures should be disabled unless it is
> absolutely needed in this environment.
>
> Remediation Script:
>
> ```
> EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; 
> RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE; 
> EXECUTE sp_configure 'remote access', 0; 
> RECONFIGURE;
> EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0; 
> RECONFIGURE;
> ```

Turning to Google before doing anything, I found [this Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) stating that (emphasis mine):

> This topic is about the "Remote Access" feature. This configuration option is an **obscure** SQL Server to SQL Server communication **feature that is deprecated, and you probably shouldn't be using it**.

Can anyone therefore please provide some clarity on the following?

1. Why is it enabled given Microsoft's description?
2. Does it need to be enabled in Azure SQLMI? Because...
3. When I run the remediation script I get this error:

> Changes to server configuration option remote access are not supported in SQL Database Managed Instances.

Answer (score 1):

Here my answers:

1. **Why is it enabled given Microsoft's description?** Because is legacy code. You probably have enabled that before 2017, it stay there unused, it migrated with you to the Managed Instance. It probably doesn't even work if you use it. Try to turn it ON or OFF, nothing will change...
2. **Does it need to be enabled in Azure SQLMI? Because...** Well, it's enabled by default. As every Managed Instance reside into a virtualized server without OS.... you only can access the Managed Instance remotely. Can you login into a Managed Instance through RDC? No, this is the proof that you only can access the Managed Instance remotely. There is no way to access it locally.
3. **When I run the remediation script I get this error:** Yeah, the Azure Vulnerability Assessment really looks like the Vulnerability Assessment that you can run from SSMS. The design is the same. Microsoft hasn't worked much around it and the fact that the remediation query doesn't work means that probably the Vulnerability Assessment is showing you a false positive.

> CONCLUSION

This really reminds me the bug I flagged about the [Extended Stored Procedure on Managed Instance](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/75890) . Extended Stored Procedure are not supported on Managed Instance. But somehow Azure Migrate migrates the to the Managed Instance. So the Vulnerability Assessement recognize them and says they are risky.

In reality they are not because there is no OS on there are n o DDL to execute.

I think with the 'remote access' we are in the same scenario